# Difference between save(false) and save(:validate => false)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

What's the difference between `save(false)` and `save(:validate => false)`? From what I can tell, the functionality is the same. The version that uses `:validate` is in the api which leads me to believe `save(false)` is a deprecated version?  This came up for me when following this: https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Create-a-guest-user. The guide has `save(false)` in there but I was getting errors when using it. I switched it to the `:validate` version and that worked fine.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

In Rails versions before than 3, `save` [was a method](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/save) in `ActiveRecord::Base` and you could pass `false` to it in order to bypass validations.

In Rails 3, `save` [was moved](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Persistence/save) to `ActiveRecord::Persistance` and since then you should pass `:validate => false` to `save` in order to bypass validations.

Comment: Note that once you've used this to persist state that violates constraints, all subsequent saves will also need validate: false.

Answer (score 35):

**All the validation from model are skipped when we use `validate: false`**

```
@user = User.new(....)

@user.save(validate: false)
```

**Action base disable validation**

http://www.dan-manges.com/blog/action-dependent-validations-and-why-on-update-is-bad

**Skip Field validation**

https://richonrails.com/articles/skipping-validations-in-ruby-on-rails

**Example**

class User < ActiveRecord::Base

validates_presence_of :password, :on => :update

end