# Make an exception when validating emails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, validation, email

I currently have an email validation as follows:

```
validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
            format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX, message: "Must be your 
            <domain name> email address." },
            uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```

This will work for all users of my application except one, an admin who does not have an email belonging to the required domain, and due to circumstances, I cannot create one for him.

How can I go about allowing this admin to register an account with his email, bypassing the regular email validation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try save method with validate: false parameter?
See [here](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Validations.html#method-i-save)

**save(options={})**

The validation process on save can be skipped by passing validate: false. The regular #save method is replaced with this when the validations module is mixed in, which it is by default.

**save!(options={})**

Attempts to save the record just like #save but will raise a RecordInvalid exception instead of returning false if the record is not valid.

You can also check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8485002/difference-between-savefalse-and-savevalidate-false)

**UPD**. As indicated in comments, this is good for few (manual) creations of admin accounts with turning off all validations.

Comment: If you need to create admin record once (e.g. in console) - that is good enough.

Comment: @nemo, try this for initial one-time creation of admin record, where you would force saving without validation for required entries

Comment: Thanks for this. I only have one exception to add and this seems to be the simplest way to do it!

Answer (score 0):

I'll do something like this:

```
validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
            format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX, message: "Must be your 
            <domain name> email address." },
            uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false },
            unless: ->(user) { user.admin? }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a condition to the validation using `:if` or `unless`. So something like:

```
validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 },
  format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX, message: "Must be your 
  <domain name> email address." },
  uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }, 
  unless: :admin?
```

You would have to define the method `admin?` to check whether the user is admin or not.

Comment: I'm new to Rails and am having trouble implementing this solution. Where do I define the `admin?` method? And would this work? How can I check if a user is an admin if the user has not yet been created?

Comment: Assuming the validation code is in your `User` class, you would have to define `admin?` as a method of `User` (the method name is arbitrary, you can choose any name you want). In that method you would have to set the criteria for who is an admin. This might mean checking the "admin" attribute for the user if there is one, or another solution like the one by @hieupham, using a whitelist. To answer your last question, validations are only applied to instances of the class/model. You would have to create an instance of a user first for its email address to be validated (before saving to the DB).

Answer (score 0):

Basically, there are 2 things required for your validation as you mentioned:

- Validate: `uniqueness, length`, this applies to both `admin` or `normal user`
- Validate: `format`, but except `Admin`

So my idea is create a whitelist for Admin:

```
validates :email, presence: true, length: { maximum: 255 }, uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }

validates format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX, message: "Must be your 
            <domain name> email address." }, unless: :in_admin_whitelist?

def in_admin_whitelist?
   email.in? ADMIN_WHITELIST
end
```

And ADMIN_WHITE_LIST should be loaded from environment variables

**config/initializers/admin.rb**

```
ADMIN_WHITELIST = ENV['ADMIN_WHITELIST'].to_s.split(/,/)
```

So your admin whitelist value format you can set in environment variable will be like:

```
admin@admin.com,admin2@admin.com
```

This will be safe and flexible enough!